# Having trouble passing type to a generic class with reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class that has the following...

```
public class Client<T> : IClient where T : IClientFactory, new()
{
    public Client(int UserID){}
}
```

and another class that implements IClientFactory

```
public class Client : IClientFactory
```

---

If the dll is referenced then I can easily do this to instantiate it.

```
var data = new namespace.Client<namespace.OtherDLL.Client>(1);
```

But obviously if I try to do it with a loaded assembly this will fail as it doesn't know the type.  I keep reading around to use Reflection to do it.  But I try to implement those ideas and have failed.  Here is an article about it.  [Can I pass a type object to a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100760/can-i-pass-a-type-object-to-a-generic-method)

```
Assembly myDllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(project.Path + project.Assembly);

Type type = myDllAssembly.GetType("Migration.Application.Client");

var data = new namespace.Client<type>(1);
```

Any help on this would be great, since I'm trying to just use a configuration file to allow me to easily drop DLL when they are ready to the client and just modify the config file to make things work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method using reflection:

```
var type = typeof(Client<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var data = (IClient)Activator.CreateInstance(type, 1)
```

Comment: I think you meant `MakeGenericType`

Comment: @dbaseman: To me `var data = namespace.Client<type>(1);` looks like a method call. But you are correct, the rest of the question looks more like he forgot the `new` there...

Comment: `Assembly myDllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(project.Path + project.Assembly);`

`Type genericClassType = myDllAssembly.GetType("GEC.Migration.SWOCS.Application.Client");`

   
`var type = GEC.Migration.FileManager.GetType("Client").MakeGenericMethod(genericClassType);`

`var data = (IClient)Activator.CreateInstance(type, userID);`


I seem to be having problems with the GetType()  Says it's not found