# Get generic type from parameter

Tags: c#, generics, xna

Im making a XNA contentloader:

```
public object[] LoadIt(KeyValuePair<Type,string>[] resources, ContentManager content)
{
    object[] result = new object[resources.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<result.Length;i++)
    {
        result[i] = content.Load<resources[i].Key>(resources[i].Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

but apparenty you're not allowed to pass a generic type from a variable, so how do i solve this then?

also if you pass the type as a generic to the method itself, then i still need the object calling the method to get the type from   variable, since ill be making a file that declares the files to load and from the strings of that file, i need to pass the type and path of the files to load

Comment: One way is to call the method using reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/869621

Comment: Can you show the load method of the ContentManager class?

Comment: Load Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx

Comment: Quesion has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100760/can-i-pass-a-type-object-to-a-generic-method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 1):

This is an XNA-specific answer to your question, but **you don't need to do that!**

You could just replace this:

```
content.Load<resources[i].Key>(resources[i].Value);
```

With this:

```
content.Load<object>(resources[i].Value);
```

XNA figures out the appropriate type on its own at runtime, from the content file itself. The generic is just for convenience and type safety.

If you wanted to verify the type of the loaded object for yourself, you could do something like this:

```
if(result[i].GetType() != resources[i].Key
        && !result[i].GetType().IsSubclassOf(resources[i].Key))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

---

Of course, one could ask why you are making a "contentloader"? I don't have enough information about what you are doing - but it *looks* like it might be unnecessary. XNA's `ContentManager` already implements ([customisable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx?Redirected=true)) caching of loaded objects - so it's likely that you could (and should) just use it directly.

Comment: I thought his reasoning may have been for dynamic content for a dynamic object.

Comment: @ShahroozJefri [Revenge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638864/165500) downvote on a random answer of mine? Stay classy.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't as the type is not compile-time constant.

What you *can* do is to use reflection without a problem as you only need `object` as return value:

```
public object[] LoadIt(KeyValuePair<Type,string>[] resources, ContentManager content)
{
    object[] result = new object[resources.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<result.Length;i++)
    {
        result[i] = content
                      .GetType()
                      .GetMethod("Load")
                      .MakeGenericMethod(resources[i].Key)
                      .Invoke(content, new object[] { resources[i].Value });
    }
    return result;
}
```